# accepting a char value through buffered reader and avoiding NumberFormatException

Tags: java

I'm accepting a character value through buffered reader but I'm getting a NumberFormatException. I'm using the char value for the different cases(menu driven program). How do i still accept and use the char value ?
{

```
System.out.println("Enter the type of pattern required");
        char ch =(char)buf.read();
        System.out.println("Enter the size");
        int x=Integer.parseInt(buf.readLine());
        switch(ch)
        {
            case 'A':
//other cases
```

}
The runtime error occurs as soon as the character is input.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it!!It's not a way u can use all the time but it can be used in simpler n shorter programs.
Just accept the other values first then accept the char value(accept char in the end--after accepting all values of all other data types).
The following is the code to accept a character to accept a character using BufferedReader:

```
    System.out.println("Enter the Character");
    char ch =(char)buf.read();
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your typed `a<Enter>`

Your buffered reader reads the `a` character:

```
char ch =(char)buf.read();
```

Then it reads the end of the line:

```
buf.readLine()
```

The end of the line is an empty string. Hence the error message (that you should **read carefully**, since it tells you what you're trying to parse as an Integer, and thus explains the problem):

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: What do you think? How about reading the end of the line, and ignoring it? Then read the next line, and parse it?

Comment: Then how does this happen. I've not even entered my next value for the compiler to move to buf .readLine

Comment: readLine() reads characters until it finds an end of line. It blocks if it doesn't find one. But you have already hit Enter after typing `a`. So it doesn't have to block. It reads everything after `a` until the end of the line.

Comment: ok(ik im pushing it now,sorry im just in 10th grade) but how can i block it after 1 letter is accepted,i mean I know I can just use a string n limit its length to one but how do i do the same using char?

Comment: You can't block anything. You can ask the user to enter just one character, then read the whole entered line, and check if it indeed contains exactly one character. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: should i post my program ,its hard to explain without it,what i require

Comment: If your program is incorrect anyway, and you can't explain what it's supposed to do, I don't see how it could help.

Comment: alright,i'll do my best to explain.my program is a menu driven program that asks the user to choose out of 2 choices of patterns.i use switch case for this.the char value accepted is the 2 choices n the int value accepted is the size of the pattern,(note: I've got no syntax errors in them)

Comment: So, do just what I said: ask the user to make a choice (A or B). Read the line. If it is equal to A or B, ask the user to enter a number, otherwise, tell the user that what he entered is not valid, and that he/she should enter A or B. Loop until he/she enter A or B.

Comment: i did that.the error is the same,i would send the code but its too long(apparently about 1256 characters longer)